# Implementing SLR and SLL instructions into MIPS Processor

Tags: mips

Given the MIPS Processor design as seen

[image: design]

I was thinking of adding the sll and srl functions to the processor. I can't seem to have any intuition on how I can retrieve the amounts of zeros to append (shift dynamically from the given shamt from [10:6] of the instruction).

Can anyone give me one headstart on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a delayed but I hope that someone in the future will find it helpful.

As you mention the bits in the shamt (shift amount) field are 5 (10 -> 6). So, 2**5=32 which corresponds to the number of bits that can be shifted right/left.

*Example:*

> Assuming that we execute a **srl** (shift right logical) operation and the value in the **shamt** field is **00010** (2 in
>   decimal) and the value in the register we want to shift is
>   **00000000000000000000000000010100**
>
> The value becomes shifted by 2 **00000000000000000000000000000101**

*Another example:*

> Instruction = **srl (Shift Right Logical)**
>   **Shamt field = 11110** (30 in decimal)             Register Value = **11110000000000000000000000000000**    Result = **00000000000000000000000000000001**
>
> The value in the register gets shifted to the right by 30 bits
>   indicated by the shamt field and becomes 1.

Depending on the value in the shamt field you shift by N bits the register that needs shifting to the right or to the left; logical or arithmetic.